# Infura Json RPC: how to call a function passing parameters?

Tags: contract-invocation, infura, eth-call

### IMPORTANT

My final goal is receive data via api on a php server and use Infura to call my contract to save the data

### Test Situation

having this test contract on rinkeby

```
contract test008 {

    mapping (uint256 => string ) private storedData;

    function set(uint _index, string memory _data_to_store) public {
        storedData[_index] = _data_to_store;
    }

    function get(uint _index) public view returns (string memory) {
        return storedData[_index];
    }
}
```

What's the right syntax to call

```
set(100, 'hello world')
```

??

Using `curl`, **How can I pass the data using the `-d` option?**

```
curl https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<project_id>\
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params": [ { "to":"hex_address_of_my_contact", "data" : " ??????  " }, "latest" ]}
```

I must specify eth address of contract in the `to`, right?

I must specify name of function, but how ?

And then I must pass parameters, but ... how ?

From the doc [of `eth_call function`](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_call)

> `data`: [optional] Hash of the method signature and encoded parameters. For details see Ethereum Contract ABI

Is this `data` param the place where specify function name and parameters for the call? If yes.... how ?!

### Core question

*if all is really about the data param ....* ....

Can I generate data hash having function name and parameters? How? Is there any doc about how to do this encoding ?
Better: do you know encoding php library?

Comment: Write a script using Web3.js, and then run this script via NodeJS.

Comment: I need a server to server solution, this is way I am using Infura and JsonRPC. I expained better, I hope, my problem,  goal and the core of my question: where pass function name and parameters and how to encode these infos if really I must use the encoded data param

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php it provides the ability to make a call to a contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web3.js can be also used in a server side environment, depending of your language implementation, and it is the best way to do it.

Doing it manually is possible, but you will need to encode all the parameters and the signature, and sign the transaction to.

Here is an article with some detail on ethereum transaction format: [Inside an Ethereum transaction](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f)

It describes all the necessary steps to achieve such thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to an article where data hasing is explained very well. Don't you know a PHP library for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update the state of your contract and for this you have to execute blockchain transaction, but **eth_call** is not for firing transactions [read more here](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_call). What can work for your case is using **eth_sendRawTransaction** [read more here](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_sendRawTransaction). In **params** you have to place the transaction data which have to be signed by the private key of the transaction creator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right API